# Use some row values as column SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to have columns that look like this:

```
KILL, DEATH, WIN, playerName
```

this is the resultset that it should be applied on
[image]

and this is the query that i use to get that resultset:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as amount, type.name as type, gamemode_statistics.Name as playerName 
FROM gamemode_statistics INNER JOIN type ON gamemode_statistics.type_id = type.id 
GROUP BY gamemode_statistics.type_id, playerName
```

i really have no clue on how to do this, i tried various ways but none of them solve my problem. Maybe i just configured my tables incorrectly?

Comment: Problems of this kind are generally best handled at the application level (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting on an ordered result set)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are the only three values you want to show as column you can do so,this will give you the count of types

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as amount, 
SUM(`type`='KILL') AS `KILL`,
SUM(`type`='DEATH') AS `DEATH`,
SUM(`type`='WIN') AS `WIN`,
 gamemode_statistics.Name as playerName 
FROM gamemode_statistics 
INNER JOIN type ON gamemode_statistics.type_id = type.id 
GROUP BY gamemode_statistics.type_id, playerName
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a pivot query, and MySQL doesn't support them directly. For a simple 3-column result, it's not too bad, but this cannot be made to work as a general solution for `n`-way arbitrary columns:

```
SELECT
    SUM(IF type='KILL', amount, 0) AS KILL,
    SUM(IF type='DEATH', amount, 0) AS DEATH
    etc..
FROM ...
```

Comment: thank you your post, this one worked as well but i can only accept 1 answer

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN type='KILL'THEN amount ELSE 0 END),0) AS KILL,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN type='DEATH'THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS DEATH
    etc..
FROM ...
```

Comment: thank you your post, this one worked as well but i can only accept 1 answer

Answer (score 0):

Consider putting your database into 3rd normal form.  http://www.andrewrollins.com/2009/08/11/database-normalization-first-second-and-third-normal-forms/

```
CREATE TABLE players (
  id int not null primary key auto_increment,
  name text not null,
... other player data
);

Create TABLE player_stats(
  player_id int not null primary key, -- this is a foreign key to the players table
  kills int not null default 0
  deaths not null default 0,
  wins not null default 0,
  ... other stats
);
```

then the query becomes something like

```
SELECT name, wins
  FROM players join player_stats on player_id = players.id
  WHERE name = 'fred';
```